# modify a list by reference inside a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I just found a way to modify conditionally a list observation inside a `data.table`. I thought it might be useful to share. Using column list in a data.table can be an interesting way of moving a lot of parameters around. It is the right way of doing it?

```
dt = data.table(id = c(1,1:2), comment = list(c("a", "b"), 1,"hello"))[]

## > dt
##  id comment
## 1:  1     a,b
## 2:  1       1
## 3:  2   hello

dt[id==1,comment:=lapply(comment,function(x) c(x,"new stuff"))]

## > dt
##    id       comment
## 1:  1 a,b,new stuff
## 2:  1   1,new stuff
## 3:  2         hello
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with `Map`

```
dt[id == 1, comment := Map(c, comment, 'new stuff')]
dt
#   id       comment
#1:  1 a,b,new stuff
#2:  1   1,new stuff
#3:  2         hello
```

Comment: Interesting. Map is a good option as well, just realized that `dt[id==1,comment:=lapply(comment,c, "new stuff")]`, would do the job as well. I've never tried it with `c`.  Thanks for sharing and nice catch for the typo above. I corrected it.

Comment: @DJJ I used `Map` in case you want to concatenate other columns as well.

Comment: ok I hadn't thought about that, it might come in handy thanks. My main purpose was to conditionally modify a list observation my adding or modifying some elements it.